# Error in the function cuMemcpyHtoD in jCUDA

Tags: cuda, jcuda

I am NEW to java programming and trying to code a matrix multiplication program in jCUDA.

While transferring the data from host to device and vice versa I use:

```
cuMemcpyHtoD(devMatrixA, Pointer.to(hostMatrixA), numRows * numCols * Sizeof.FLOAT);
cuMemcpyHtoD(devMatrixB, Pointer.to(hostMatrixA), numRows * numCols * Sizeof.FLOAT);
cuMemcpyDtoH(Pointer.to(hostMatrixC), devMatrixC, numRows * numCols * Sizeof.FLOAT);
```

Here, the devMatrixA, devMatrixB and devMatrixC are the matrices to be stored on device memory. And hostMatrixA, hostMatrixB and hostMatrixC are the matrices stored on my Host memory.

When I call above functions for data transfer, it gives me following error 'The method to(byte[]) in the type Pointer is not applicable for the arguments (float[][])' with 'to' in 'Pointer.to(' is red underlined. I am using eclipse. I have given my complete code as below.

Pardon my java knowledge, and please suggest if I am going into wrong direction.

```
Package JCudaMatrixAddition;
import static jcuda.driver.JCudaDriver.*;

import java.io.*;

import jcuda.*;
import jcuda.driver.*;
import jcuda.Pointer;
import jcuda.Sizeof;


public class JCudaMatrixAddition {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        // Enable exceptions and omit all subsequent error checks
        JCudaDriver.setExceptionsEnabled(true);

        // Create the PTX file by calling the NVCC
        String ptxFilename = preparePtxFile("JCudaMatrixAdditionKernel.cu");

        //Initialize the driver and create a context for the first device.
        cuInit(0);
        CUdevice device = new CUdevice();
        cuDeviceGet (device, 0);
        CUcontext context = new CUcontext();
        cuCtxCreate(context, 0, device);

        //Load PTX file
        CUmodule module = new CUmodule();
        cuModuleLoad(module,ptxFilename);

        //Obtain a function pointer to the Add function
        CUfunction function = new CUfunction();
        cuModuleGetFunction(function, module, "add");

        int numRows = 32;
        int numCols = 32;

        //Allocate and fill Host input Matrices:
        float hostMatrixA[][] = new float[numRows][numCols];
        float hostMatrixB[][] = new float[numRows][numCols];
        float hostMatrixC[][] = new float[numRows][numCols];


        for(int i = 0; i<numRows; i++)

        {
            for(int j = 0; j<numCols; j++)
            {
                hostMatrixA[i][j] = (float) 1.0;
                hostMatrixB[i][j] = (float) 1.0;
            }
        }
        // Allocate the device input data, and copy the
        // host input data to the device
        CUdeviceptr devMatrixA = new CUdeviceptr();
        cuMemAlloc(devMatrixA, numRows * numCols * Sizeof.FLOAT);

        //This is the part where it gives me the error
        cuMemcpyHtoD(devMatrixA, Pointer.to(hostMatrixA), numRows * numCols * Sizeof.FLOAT);

        CUdeviceptr devMatrixB = new CUdeviceptr();
        cuMemAlloc(devMatrixB, numRows * numCols * Sizeof.FLOAT);

        //This is the part where it gives me the error
        cuMemcpyHtoD(devMatrixB, Pointer.to(hostMatrixA), numRows * numCols * Sizeof.FLOAT);

        //Allocate device matrix C to store output
        CUdeviceptr devMatrixC = new CUdeviceptr();
        cuMemAlloc(devMatrixC, numRows * numCols * Sizeof.FLOAT);

        // Set up the kernel parameters: A pointer to an array
        // of pointers which point to the actual values.

        Pointer kernelParameters = Pointer.to(Pointer.to(new int[]{numRows}),
                                   Pointer.to(new int[]{numRows}), 
                                   Pointer.to(devMatrixA),
                                   Pointer.to(devMatrixB),
                                   Pointer.to(devMatrixC));

        //Kernel thread configuration
        int blockSize = 32;
        int gridSize = 1;

        cuLaunchKernel(function, 
                       gridSize, 1, 1,
                       blockSize, 32, 1,
                       0, null, kernelParameters, null);

        cuCtxSynchronize();
        // Allocate host output memory and copy the device output
        // to the host.

        //This is the part where it gives me the error
        cuMemcpyDtoH(Pointer.to(hostMatrixC), devMatrixC, numRows * numCols * Sizeof.FLOAT);

        //verify the result
        for (int i =0; i<numRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j =0; j<numRows; j++)
            {
                System.out.print("   "+ hostMatrixB[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        cuMemFree(devMatrixA);
        cuMemFree(devMatrixB);
        cuMemFree(devMatrixC);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not copy a `float[][]` array from the host to the device directly.

When you create a `float[][]` array, then this is not a large array of `float` values. Instead, it is an *array of arrays*. Imagine that you could even create an array like

```
float array[][] = new float[3];
array[0] = new float[42];
array[1] = null;
array[2] = new float[1234];
```

This is simply not a contiguous memory block, and thus, such an array can not be copied to the device.

When handling matrices in CUDA (not only in JCuda, but in CUDA in general), they are usually represented as 1-dimensional arrays. So in this case, you could declare your matrices as

```
float hostMatrixA[] = new float[numRows*numCols];
```

In order to access the matrix elements, you have to compute the appropriate index:

```
int row = ...;
int col = ...;
hostMatrix[col+row*numCols] = 123.0f; // Column-major

// Or
hostMatrix[row+col*numRows] = 123.0f; // Row-major
```

The difference between the last two lines is that one assumes column-major order, and the other assumes row-major order. See the [Wikipedia site about row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) for details.

Some side notes:

The CUDA matrix libraries like CUBLAS use column-major ordering, so it is probably a good idea to follow the same convention. Particularly when you later want to use CUBLAS/JCublas functions. For example, the [cublasSgeam](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-lt-t-gt-geam) function already offers the functionality to perform a matrix addition.

When you *only* want to do a matrix addition, you will not see a speedup when using CUDA/JCuda. I wrote a summary about this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22868938/3182664).

And BTW: Technically, it is possible to use "2D arrays". The [JCudaDriverSample](http://jcuda.org/samples/JCudaDriverSample.java) shows how this can be done. But it is rather inconvenient and *not* recommended for matrix operations.