# Jcuda parallelize for loop

Tags: java, cuda, parallel-processing, jcuda

I am a newbie in cuda for Java.
I have a simple task to do: parallelize a for loop.

my for loop is pretty simple, I have an array of objects and I have to perform some "evaluation" to each object in the array:

```
     for (int i=0; i < vec.length; i++){              
         int val =  evaluate((vec[i]));
     }
```

I was wondering I can I parallelize this. I only found examples of complex things in JCuda.

Thanks for helping

Maria

Comment: The [JCudaVectorAdd sample](http://www.jcuda.org/samples/samples.html) should be easily adaptable to your case, and it is used in a [tutorial](http://www.jcuda.org/tutorial/TutorialIndex.html) as well.  Doing arbitrary operations in JCuda often involves writing a CUDA kernel directly (the kernel is written in C/C++), as that sample demonstrates.  Your CUDA kernel could hold the operations for the `evaluate` method.

Comment: Three people already voted as "too broad" - and they may be right. Maybe you want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866901/using-java-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda/22868938#22868938 to decide whether what you are going to do there actually makes sense...