# Are Java 8 Lambda expressions using GPU?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, gpu

I recently got in touch with Java 8 and I'm trying to learn Lambda expressions.
I want to do some graphics calculations, my code so far:

```
    IntStream.range(0, (screenSize.width * screenSize.height)).parallel().forEach(id -> { 
        int x = id % screenSize.width;
        int y = ((id-x) / screenSize.width);
        /*look up what color this pixel is.*/
    });
```

Now all this Code is for graphics, everything is basic Math (plus, minus, multiply, modulo), except for `bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y)` and operations with `java.awt.Color`, and it can be done for each pixel seperately.

Now the question: Is it possible to run this on the GPU? Or is this even automatically GPU-based? (I remember reading this somewhere, but I'm not sure)

Comment: I don't think so. There is a project on OpenJDK that (hopes) supports such a thing though: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Sumatra/Main

Comment: possible similarity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866901/using-java-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda (Also read about Sumatra http://openjdk.java.net/projects/sumatra/ )

Comment: In fact, there already **is** a solution for this: https://github.com/aparapi/aparapi . It can be considered as a "predecessor" of project Sumatra (or, as they called in the mailing lis: Aparapi is a "tracing bullet" of what is done in Sumatra). It's also mentioned in the list at the end of the question that kicker86 linked to in the above comment.

Comment: But, if I got it correctly, aparapi only works with arrays of primitive data types. This would be much work, to convert everything into arrays of int or double. Sumatra sounded like it would be able to take nearly every java code. Am I right?

Comment: Sure, Aparapi can not automatically convert *all* Java constructs to GPU code. There are approaches for this, like Sumatra or [rootbeer](https://github.com/pcpratts/rootbeer1), but it's complex (particularly, the interdependencies with the JIT, and the different memories that are involved!), and I doubt that there will be a generic solution for this soon.

Comment: not GPU, but hotspot may auto-vectorize (SIMD instructions) some loops. Although the support for that is not as advanced as, for example, GCC's autovectorization

Comment: I feel dumb to ask this, but as a nonnative English speaker and a beginner in java programming: what means vectorization?

Answer (score 10):

The JavaVM implementation is free to implement the Java bytecode interpretation however it wants as long as the results are correct. It is free to run anything on the GPU when it wants to. However, I don't know of any Java implementation which does this currently. There is a project to add GPU acceleration to OpenJDK ([Project Sumatra](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Sumatra)), and you guessed correctly: It focuses on the stream API because it was designed to write code which can be parallelized. But this is currently far from production-ready and currently it doesn't seem like there is anyone working on it.

When you want to run computations on the GPU from a Java program today, you will need a library which wraps a GPU computing API like OpenCL using the Java Native Interface (for OpenCL there is [JOCL](http://www.jocl.org/)). Be prepared to learn a new programming language, because every GPU computing API takes instructions in a different language and none of them is very similar to Java.

Comment: As long as I know, currently nobody works on project Sumatra, so it's unlikely to see it even in JDK 10.

Comment: Sumatra is no longer maintain. http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/graal-dev/2015-February/002921.html

Comment: What is about **Aparapi**? Is this easier to use than **JOCL**?

Comment: @ErikBrendel No idea, never heard about it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are doing. If those really are general parallel computations, connecting GPGPU things like OpenCL may have its benefits, even though integrating it won't be easy.

However, you are doing graphics computatuons, as you said. It's what shaders are designed for. A vertex shader is run once per vertex, then unseen elements are cut, then the scene is split into fragments (size of a pixel each) and each of them is then run through a fragment shader.

I've worked with GLSL a bit, so I can tell your code looks quite simple in shaders. X and Y for each fragment are calculated in between vertex and a fragment shaders by interpolating vertex coordinates (that's how `varying` variables work), texture sampling is done via `texture2d` function.

Answer (score 0):

There is a research project [1] to do exactly this. It is an extension of the JVM (Graal VM actually) to generate C OpenCL code from the byte-codes at run-time.

[1] http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2627381