# Can Java image display choose video card on a computer?

Tags: java, image, jogl

We have a **Java** application running on **Linux**. The application needs to display images (with jogl). My computer has **two video** cards, one is the integrated video card and another is a NVIDIA added by our engineer.

I am just wondering is it possible for the **Java** application to **choose** which video card to use? how about **dynamically**?

Comment: "*[...] is it possible for the Java application to choose which video card to use?*" - In general, no. Java cannot communicate with specialized hardware like graphic cards or webcams. There is, however, the possibility to use the JNI to communicate with the hardware's driver directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Java with Nvidia GPU's (cuda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22866901/using-java-with-nvidia-gpus-cuda)

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered on the official JogAmp forum. At first, there is no cross-platform GPU manufacturer agnostic way of doing that in plain OpenGL. [NVidia GPU affinity extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/WGL_NV_gpu_affinity.txt) is not exposed in JOGL and anyway, it would not work with non NVidia hardware.